# Centered button over responsive image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pux7q/1/)

```
.btn {
text-transform: uppercase;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 15px;
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #000;
padding: 25px 80px 25px 80px;
font-size: 18px; }
```

So I have this image, which is responsive and button over it which should be always centered.

If you move the window width, you'll see that image changes size quite a bit and I would like to know what is the best way to set button so it will change size automatically with image as well so it gets bigger/smaller?

Is there a better solution for this besides setting a lot of @media queries here?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using absolute positioning you can't currently use margins to achieve this.

However, if you use a new div that wraps the anchor, set it to `position: absolute` and then center the anchor inside that, it'll work.

```
<div class="logo">
    <img src="http://s13.postimg.org/9y14o777r/imgholder.png" />
    <div><a href="#" class="btn">Register</a></div>
</div>

.logo div {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 25%
}
.logo a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 250px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pux7q/2/)

You can adjust the sizing and vertical centering as you need, and add some responsive css or `min-width` to control too-small sizes.

Comment: Thanks but my question was how to make button resize together with image so it adjust to image size automatically and gets bigger/smaller.

Comment: Ok, this solution will help adjust the centering since you had fixed centering pixel values. You can use media queries, use `%` measurements. However, there still needs to be `min-width` so the text doesn't get trampled